# django admin inline many to many custom fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-1.5

Hi I am trying to customize my inlines in django admin.

Here are my models:

```
class Row(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Table(models.Model):
    rows = models.ManyToManyField(Row, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

and my admin:

```
class RowInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Table.rows.through
    fields = ['name']


class TableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        RowInline,
    ]
    exclude = ('rows',)
```

However I get this error

> ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/table_app/table/1/
>
> 'RowInline.fields' refers to field 'name' that is missing from the
>   form.

How is that possible ?

Comment: change `model = Table.rows.through` to `model = Row`

Comment: does not work Row has no foreign key to Table

Comment: I'm coming across the exact same problem.  I added a bounty to hopefully give it some more attention.

Comment: The `RowInline` class specifies its model as `Table.rows.through` (the autogenerated intermediate model for the `Table.rows` many-to-many relation) and then asks for its `name` field — but the intermediate model has no such field, it only has two foreign keys: one to `Table` (named `from_`) and one to `Row` (named `to`). `TabularInline` (or indeed any of the `*Inline` classes) will not be able to handle your needs; you'll likely need to implement a custom subclass.

Comment: I put an updated question more inline with what I'm doing Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562645/django-many-to-many-inline-how-to-show-fields-referenced-by-through-model

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
class RowInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Table.rows.through
    fields = ['name']
```

This presents a problem because Table.rows.through represents an intermediate model. If you would like to understand this better have a look at your database. You'll see an intermediate table which references this model.  It is probably named something like apname_table_rows. This intermeditate model does not contain the field, name.  It just has two foreign key fields: table and row.  (And it has an id field.)

If you need the name it can be referenced as a readonly field through the rows relation.

```
class RowInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Table.rows.through
    fields = ['row_name']
    readonly_fields = ['row_name']

    def row_name(self, instance):
        return instance.row.name
    row_name.short_description = 'row name'


class TableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        RowInline,
    ]
    exclude = ('rows',)
```

Comment: That seems like a great idea but it's not working for me.  I even made the function return simply "test" to rule out problems with the instance but it still can't seem to find the field.

Comment: Can you post a stack trace?

Comment: That is a good approach for *only* displaying field values. `readonly_fields` only displayed as a label, not as a `form field`. So django can get the value and display it. But you can not use this approach to insert or update data through inlines.

Comment: Edited the answer to have both `fields` and `readonly_fields`, which is what worked for me using recent django.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. By showing only read only fields, we can prevent loading the whole table in <select> in inlines

Answer (score 9):

Django can not display it as you expected. Because there is an *intermediary join table* which joins your tables. In your example:

admin.py:

```
class RowInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Table.rows.through  # You are not addressing directly Row table but intermediary table
    fields = ['name']
```

As the above note, `model` in `RowInline` addressing following table in your database, not Your `Row` table and model

```
table: your-app-name_table_row
--------------------------------
id       | int not null
table_id | int
row_id   | int
```

You can think it like there is an **imaginary** table in your model that joins the two tables.

```
class Table_Row(Model):
    table = ForeignKey(Table)
    row = ForeignKey(Row)
```

So if you edit your Inline as following

```
class RowInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Table.rows.through  # You are not addressing directly Row table but intermediary table
    fields = ['row', 'table']
```

you will not see any error or exception. Because your `model` in `RowInline` addresses an intermediary table and that table do have those fields. Django can virtualize the imaginary table `Table_Row` up to here and can handle this.

But we can use relations in admin, with using `__`. If your code do have a `ForeignKey` relation instead of `ManyToManyField` relation, then following be valid in your admin

```
 class Row(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Table(models.Model):
    rows = models.ForeignKey(Row, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

and your admin:

```
class RowInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Table
    fields = ['rows__name']
```

Because you will have real Models and djnago can evaluate `__` relation on them

But if you try that in your structure:

```
 class Row(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Table(models.Model):
    rows = models.ManyToManyField(Row, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

and your admin:

```
class RowInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Table.rows.through 
    fields = ['row__name']
```

it will `raise Exception`! Because you do not have **real** table in your model, and django can not evaluate `__` relations on virtual models it designs on top of its head.

#### Conclusion:

In your `Inline`s addressing `ManyToMany` relations, you are dealing with an *imaginary intermediary model* and you can not use `fields` or`exclude` attributes on that because your *imaginary* model do not have those fields and django can not handle relations ober that *imaginary* table.  Following will be acceptable

```
class RowInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Table.rows.through 
    # No fields or exclude declarations in here
```

and django will display combo boxes for your *virtual intermediary table options* and add a fancy green `+` sign to add new records, but you will can not have inline fields to add new records directly to your database within the same single page. Djnago can not handle this on a single page.

You can try creating **real** intermediary table and show it using [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield), but thats totally a longer job and I do not test it to see its results.

**Update:** There is also the reason why django do not let something like that. Consider following:

```
          Table   | Table_Row |   Row
       -----------+-----------+---------
Start      5      |           |          
Step 1     5      |           |    1
Step 2     5      |    5-1    |    1
```

At the beginning, You have a table with no related Rows, you want to add a row to the table... For joining a row with a table, **you must first create a row** so you execute step 1. After You **do create** your row, you can create `Table_Row` record to join these two. So in contains more than a single database insertion. Django crew may avoid such usage since it contains multiple inserts and operation is related more tables.

But this is  just an assumption on the reason of the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In your admin.py try this

```
    class RowInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = Table.rows.through
        list_display = ('name',)


    class TableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        inlines = [
            RowInline,
            ]
        readonly_fields = ('rows',)
```

Comment: This solved my problem for when in the admin tool I don't want to display the original table and just the through relationship. Thanks!