# Django Many to Many Inline - how to show fields referenced by through model?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-1.6

I'm trying to customize and many to many inline in the django Admin, but I'm not able to display the fields of the underlying models.

Here's a simplified example.  Maybe you can tell me how to reference them?

Here are my models:

```
class Clown(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def edit_link(self):
        return ...

class Circus(models.Model):
    clowns = models.ManyToManyField(Clown, blank=True, through='WorkedAt')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class WorkedAt(models.Model):
    clown = models.ForeignKey(Clown)
    circus = models.ForeignKey(Circus)
```

and my admin:

```
class ClownInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = WorkedAt
    fields = ['clown__name','clown__edit_link']


class CircusAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ClownInline,
    ]
    exclude = ('clowns',)
```

However I get this error:

```
Unknown field(s) (clown__name) specified for WorkedAt
```

(I'm on Django 1.6)

**Update:** 
Why won't this work either.  (Added calculated field to through model.)

```
class Clown(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def edit_link(self):
        return ...

class Circus(models.Model):
    clowns = models.ManyToManyField(Clown, blank=True, through='WorkedAt')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class WorkedAt(models.Model):
    clown = models.ForeignKey(Clown)
    circus = models.ForeignKey(Circus)
    @property
    def edit_link(self):
        return self.clown.edit_link()
```

and my admin:

```
class ClownInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = WorkedAt
    fields = ['edit_link']


class CircusAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ClownInline,
    ]
    exclude = ('clowns',)
```

Comment: The `fields` have to be a database field from the `WorkedAt` model. It cannot be a field of underlying model. In this case, you can have the inline as `Clown` on the `Circus` model, and do away with `WorkedAd` altogether

Comment: Ok, check out my update.  If I added a method right to the through model why won't even that show up?

Comment: Can you post a stack trace?

Comment: Defining both `fields` and `readonly_fields` should make this work.

Answer (score 6):

Try this. Hope it solves your problem

```
class ClownInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = WorkedAt
    fields = ['clown_name', 'clown_edit_link']
    readonly_fields = ['clown_name', 'clown_edit_link']

    def clown_name(self, instance):
        return instance.clown.name
    clown_name.short_description = 'clow name'

    def clown_edit_link(self, instance):
        url = reverse("admin:%s_%s_change" % (instance.clown._meta.app_label, instance.clown._meta.module_name), args=(instance.clown.pk,))
        return '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (url, instance.clown.name)
    clown_edit_link.allow_tags = True


class CircusAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ClownInline,
    ]
    exclude = ('clowns',)
```

Comment: Big thanks for the attempt!  For some reason it's still not working.  I even had the your method ClownInline.clown_name return a simple string 'test' to rule out any issues, but it still can't find field clown_name.

Comment: **module_name** should be **model_name** in:

url = reverse("admin:%s_%s_change" % (instance.clown._meta.app_label, instance.clown._meta.module_name) # <- here, args=(instance.clown.pk,))

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if anyone still needs this, because this question is 4 years old but this solved my problem for in `Django 2.0.3`:

```
# models.py
class Clown(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def edit_link(self):
        return ...


class Circus(models.Model):
    clowns = models.ManyToManyField(Clown, blank=True, through='WorkedAt')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class WorkedAt(models.Model):
    clown = models.ForeignKey(Clown)
    circus = models.ForeignKey(Circus)


# admin.py
class WorkedAtInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = WorkedAt
    extra = 1


class WorkedAtAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (WorkedAtInline,)


admin.site.register(Clown, WorkedAtAdmin)
```

Hope this helps anyone that stumbles upon this problem and looks into this answer.